# Build Compile error on bat file The command "call "C:\source\repos\MyFolder\MyBat_Debug.bat"" exited with code 127

Tags: c#, batch-file, jenkins

I have a simple bat file where I am just copying over the nuget .pdb files to some paths
I am able to compile the code in the visual studio however when my project gets build in Jenkins I get the following error The command "call "C:\source\repos\MyFolder\MyBat_Debug.bat"" exited with code 127.

Here is my csproj file where I have the command

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="call &quot;C:\source\repos\MyFolder\MyBat_Debug.bat&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

Here is the bat file

```
@echo OFF
COPY C:\source\repos\MyFolder\Controller\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Common.pdb C:\source\repos\Project\MyController\bin\Debug
```

Comment: try  `<Exec Command="C:\source\repos\MyFolder\MyBat_Debug.bat" />`

Comment: still facing the same error

Comment: and the batch file alone is executable?